# How to store overtime location info in Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, android-sqlite

I'm working on an app that collects user's location data overtime (like every 5 seconds while driving it should update their location). Ultimately I want these periodic location updates to sync up to my Rails server.

I'm wondering what the best way is to store/sync them up to my server. It doesn't seem like a good idea to sync them up with the server after every update, perhaps every hour it should sync the last 720 updates from the previous hour?

Is local SQLLite the best way to save those on the device in between syncing with the server? Any other better ideas with battery usage/performance in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will drain battery too quickly if you generate data every 5 sec. 
I created an app that use Google Map Api .

If user has to see his data you must sync data frequently.
If not you can sync in 12 hours from your sqlLite.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - it's an app that a user would be using while driving. How often would you recommend pulling location updates from a user while driving to ensure we're able to maintain where they're at? Every 10 seconds? 15?

Comment: In 15 sec he can drive a long distance. It depends on area you want to implement this app. If it is a metro city and traffic is too fast you must implement with 5 sec. You can save some battery power by using "FUSE LOCATION" also.

Comment: I'll definitely check that out! Thanks again